# Is it possible to use facebook api using simple/basic auth?

Tags: php, facebook, oauth

I'm not a fulltime nor professional developer. So i make app for my own or for my friends. I dont want to register my app.
Recently twitter has stopped basic auth and now twitter requires us to do Oauth :(
What about with facebook? Is it possible to do basic auth? *what about friendster too?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, see the [Facebook developers page for authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).

> Facebook Platform uses the OAuth 2.0 protocol for authentication and authorization.

Friendster requires that you register the application to receive an API key.